# function ta.rsi Pinescript on TradingView

Tags: function, pine-script

I dont't understand why my script doesn't save my function ta.rsi(close,9).
I have the same problem with math.max
I think I didn't make a mistake in my code

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Those `ta.` and `math.` namespaces have been introduced in `v5`.

It looks like your pinescript is in an older version.

You should call those functions without the namespaces.

```
vrsi = rsi(close, 9)
```